# How do I debug "The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain"?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to build a webapi service in aspnet core, on Linux Mint (which is an Ubuntu variant.)

When I try to access an endpoint, whether from the Swagger UI in Chrome, from Postman, or from Chrome directly, I get exceptions:

> **AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain**
>
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
>
> **HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.**
>
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(bool async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Chrome is displaying the "Not secure" button, clicking on which displays:

> Your connection to this site is not secure

I can click on "Certificate(invalid)" which brings up "Certificate Viewer: localhost", where I can see the details of the certificate, but I see nothing in the Chrome Certificate Viewer, or in the exceptions, that indicates exactly why the certificate is invalid.

Where can I find this certificate?

How do I determine why it's failing validation?

How do I get it to not fail validation?

Comment: "PartialChain" is likely the problem. Look at the chain provided by the server to see if it is correct, with e.g. `openssl s_client` (with `-servername` if below 1.1.1) or `keytool -printcert -sslserver` or if on the internet ssllabs.com/ssltest or www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html . Or in Chrome instead of looking at 'Details' look at 'Certification Path' (at least on Windows; if this is Chrome on Linux, Mac, phone or Chromebook it may be different).